# Sum Vector Components in OpenCL (SSE-like)

Tags: opencl

Is there a single instruction to calculate the sum of all components of a `float4`, e.g., in OpenCL?

```
float4 v;
float desiredResult = v.x + v.y + v.z + v.w;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
float4 v;
float desiredResult = dot(v, (float4)(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
```

It's a little more work, because you're multiplying each component by one before adding them, but some GPUs have a dot product instruction built in. So might be faster; might be slower. It depends on your hardware.